# How disable "my account" box from all mirage theme in dspace

Tags: xml, xslt, dspace, mirage

i need remove the box "my account" from mirage theme in `dspace`, I found this, but only works for the box in the frontpage.

```html
<xsl:template match="dri:list[@id='aspect.viewArtifacts.Navigation.list.account']">
  <xsl:if test="//dri:metadata[@element='request' and @qualifier='URI']/text() != ''">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I have dspace-5.5,
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi again, i fix it, just need insert this code in page_estructure. <xsl:template match="dri:options/dri:list[@n = 'account']" priority="5">
</xsl:template>

Comment: post this as an answer to your own questions, that is a better way to let others now. People don't always look at comments :-)